# VS2015 debugger can't see members of a forward declared c++ class

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2015, forward-declaration, pimpl-idiom

Suppose a code:

ClassA.h

```
class ClassAImpl;

class ClassA
{
public:
    ClassA();
    // ... some other methods here

private:
    ClassAImpl *m_classAImpl;
};
```

ClassA.cpp:

```
#include "ClassA.h"

class ClassAImpl
{
public:
    ClassAImpl(int field) : m_Field(field) {}

public:
    int m_Field;
    // ... other class members here
};

ClassA::ClassA()
{
    m_classAImpl = new ClassAImpl(123);
}

// ... etc
```

Now, when I debug this code, and inspect a variable which have a type of ClassA, I can't inspect m_classAImpl. Debugger shows me just a pointer without any members (I want to inspect m_Field, for example). As if ClassAImpl doesn't have any members at all.

Am I missing something?

Thanx.
Dan.

Comment: "Help" -> "Send Feedback..." -> "Report a Problem..."

Comment: Where is the definition of the class? On the same project, or in a different library? The PDB file is available and loaded?

Comment: Both .cpp and .h are in the same project - a DLL. I'm debug EXE, that uses that DLL. I can easily step into ClassA methods, set breakpoints, etc

Comment: @RustyX, do you think it's a bug of VS2015? What about other frameworks? I just don't have another experience...

Comment: ***do you think it's a bug of VS2015?*** The same behavior happens in Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: @Danil, Can you share a screen shot about the result in your side? How about using the VS2017? To really repro this issue, would you please share a sample using one drive? If we get the same issue, I will help you report this issue.

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT, I will do tomorrow

Comment: Here: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AlJiqC-x9K6AgQ33HHtp24Y4szWG

Comment: @Danil, Can you share a screen shot about the result you got in your site?

Comment: Here is a screen shot: https://1drv.ms/i/s!AlJiqC-x9K6AgQ6t1Ofddd_3pdXL

Comment: UPDATE: When I step into ClassA constructor and inspect private class, I begin to see it's internals. If you can read Russian, a little discussion here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ru-RU/f0c64c37-29dd-4270-8492-a9d5c940a02b/-vs2015-forward-declaration-?forum=vsru

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use .natvis file to declare the member of forward declared class, and the information declare by .natvis file will included in the pdb file.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/create-custom-views-of-native-objects?view=vs-2022

Many stl class declared their state in STL.natvis.

For example, std::mutex declared lock state in STL.natvis, in debug watch window, you can't watch member of std::mutex,but you can watch state of std::mutex.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. This topic a bit outdated for me, but I will give it a try on ocassion.